# EF6 Code-first project - can I use it in .NET Core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database that I created using *EF6*. I have a VS project (library) that includes only my models and `DbContext`. Whenever I need to use my database I just reference that library DLL.

I have a few questions about that:

1. What happens if I lose this DLL somehow, but still have my models? Am I able to recreate my library?
2. What if I want to start using .NET Core? As far as I understand, I would have to use EF Core, right?. How can I get the same experience as I had with my DLL (same models).

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Chw. Much better now

Comment: i did not get your 3rd question

Comment: @DarshanDave I fixed that now, I hope it's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you still have the Code of your Models you can simply recreate the DLL. It gets recreated as you rebuild anyway.
2. You can also use the full entity framework together with .Net Core but that would make your application depending on classic .Net again.
   The entity framework core works similar in many ways and also a lot of the old annotations work. You should be able to port you Model easily from EF6 to EF Core if it is not to complicated. Just be aware of some limitations regarding group by that will be resolved in 2.1
   Because .Net Core is independent of the OS you won't be shuffeling around DLL's for you dependencys. One way is to use independet projects and release them as packages. So you can consume them in other projects with the package manager.

Comment: Thanks, that's very valuable input. Actually I totally forgot that DLLs don't work with Core, you're right. I'll have to read some more how it's done with these "packages". I guess I'll have to create .NET Core Library

Comment: You are Welcome. With .Net core it depends for wich platform you deploy it. If you use it on windows there still will be DLL's as a build output. But if you start referencing external DLL's, your project will only be able to run on Windows. So it's recommended to reference a different project or package. This way they can still be build independent from the OS.